# Read several PDF files into R with pdf_text

Tags: r, pdf, vector

I have several PDF files in my directory. I have downloaded them previously, no big deal so far.

I want to read all those files in R. My idea was to use the "pdf_text" function from the "pdftools" package and write a formula like this:

```
mypdftext <- pdf_text(files)
```

Where "files" is an object that gathers all the PDF file names, so that I don't have to write manually all the names. Because I have actually downlaoded a lot of files, it would avoid me to write:

```
mypdftext <- pdf_text("file1.pdf", "file2.pdf", and many more files...)
```

To create the object "pdflist", I used "files <- list.files (pattern = "pdf$")"
The “files” vector contains all the PDF file names.

But "files" does not work with pdf_text function, probably because it's a vector. What can I do instead?

Comment: You can `Map` over the different file names: `Map(pdf_text, files)` and that will return a list. It depends on how exactly you want to combine all those files as to what you do next.

Comment: You can try using an `apply`-style function e.g. `mypdftexts <- lapply(files, {function(x) pdf_text(x)})`. This will return a list with each element being the text from a pdf file.

Answer (score 3):

maybe this is not the best solution but this works for me:

```
library(pdftools)

# Set your path here.
your_path = 'C:/Users/.../pdf_folder'
setwd(your_path)
getwd()



lf = list.files(path=getwd(), pattern=NULL, all.files=FALSE,
           full.names=FALSE)


#Creating a list to iterate 
my_pdfs = {}

#Iterate. Asssign each element of list files, to a list. 
for (i in 1:length(lf)){my_pdfs[i] <- pdf_text(lf[i])}

#Calling the first pdf of the list.
my_pdfs[1]
```

Then you can assign each of the pdfs to a  single file of whatever you want. Of course, each file will be saved in each element of the list. Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `lapply` over the vector that contains the location of every pdf file (`files`). I would recommend using `list.files(..., full.names = T)` to get the complete location of each pdf file. This should work.

```
mypdfs<-lapply(files, pdf_text)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've used that before and it gives good results, however it wouldn't help me much with the rest of my code.
Maybe I should rephrase a bit... In the code above, list is a character vector, but the fuction pdf_text needs a string... So I should to transform a character into a string?